# cart_product.remove not updating cart total in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I am using cart_product.remove  api to remove products from the customers cart. The Api works fine and removes the product from cart. But it does not update the cart total after removing the product from cart.

How do I update the cart total?

Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same problem, did you find a fix for this?

Comment: did you find any way to update shopping cart ?

Answer (score 1):

You will face this problem only when the cart is actually empty but there were products added before. These are my observations while using SOAP that will help you overcome this:

1. When you delete an item from the Cart, the totals will not update if the cart is empty. Do not use the SOAP totals when you know your cart is empty.
2. If an item is added or exists in cart with quantity > 1, make sure while deleting you pass the quantity to delete too. It looks like Magento delete by only one quantity otherwise or create an unexpected scenario.

So go ahead and add another item to this cart, if you did your delete properly, the totals will recalculate.